# alfresco 5.2 adjuntar nodo a correo con js desde consola

Tags: javascript

Necesito un codigo que me permita enviar un correo desde la consola del alfresco5.2 del share y que me permita adjuntar un documento teniendo su noderef. El siguiente es mi codigo actual, pero parece no funcionar bien.

```
var referenciaNodo = "workspace://SpacesStore/5d29bc23-73ef-409c-b117-741ff41fdece";
var nameFile = 'PLANTILLA_COMPRA_CERTIFICADOS_'+'.xlsx';

var file =companyhome.childByNamePath(nameFile);
var fileext= ".xlsx";

var mail = actions.create("mail");      
var person = people.getPerson("username");
mail.parameters.to = person.properties["cm:email"]; 
mail.parameters.subject = "Reporte Adjunto";
mail.parameters.from = "alfresco@domain.do";
mail.parameters.template = companyhome.childByNamePath("Data Dictionary/Email Templates/notify_email_es.html.ftl");

mail.parameters.node_to_attach = file;
mail.parameters.attachment_extension = fileext;     
mail.execute(search.findNode(referenciaNodo));
```